# Auto copy files to phone upon connecting though mtp

Tags: sync, mtp

I want to create some setup that will auto copy files (specifically videos) to my phone from a specific workstation directory, upon establishing an mtp connection.

How can I achieve the above?

I know about mtp-tools but I don't know how can I automatically trigger a copy action.